# How can I adjust the space between each subplot for a 5*3 subplots setup? [MatLab]

Tags: matlab, subplot

I know I need to have a format like this below but I could not figure out what are the values should be in after the 'position' parameter.
Also, I want to keep the title for each subplot.

ESPECIALLY, I don't want the vertical distance between each column of the subplot so large. It seems the distance between each column of the subplot becomes larger as the number of rows of subplots get larger.

Thank you for your hints/helps in advance.

```
subplot(5,3,1);imshow(a1_1,[]);title('(a1)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,2);imshow(a2_1,[]);title('(a2)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,3);imshow(a3_1,[]);title('(a3)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,4);imshow(b1_1,[]);title('(b1)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,5);imshow(b2_1,[]);title('(b2)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,6);imshow(b3_1,[]);title('(b3)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,7);imshow(c1_1,[]);title('(c1)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,8);imshow(c2_1,[]);title('(c2)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,9);imshow(c3_1,[]);title('(c3)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,10);imshow(d1_1,[]);title('(d1)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,11);imshow(d2_1,[]);title('(d2)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,12);imshow(d3_1,[]);title('(d3)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,13);imshow(e1_1,[]);title('(e1)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,14);imshow(e2_1,[]);title('(e2)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
subplot(5,3,15);imshow(e3_1,[]);title('(e3)');set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
ha=get(gcf,'children');
set(ha(1),'position',[ ])
set(ha(2),'position',[ ])
set(ha(3),'position',[ ])
set(ha(4),'position',[ ])
set(ha(5),'position',[ ])
set(ha(6),'position',[ ])
set(ha(7),'position',[ ])
set(ha(8),'position',[ ])
set(ha(9),'position',[ ])
set(ha(10),'position',[ ])
set(ha(11),'position',[ ])
set(ha(12),'position',[ ])
set(ha(13),'position',[ ])
set(ha(14),'position',[ ])
set(ha(15),'position',[ ])
```

Comment: You might want to use [`tiledlayout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) instead.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm not sure how to adjust the vertical space among the subplots, as I said, the distance between each column of the subplot becomes larger as the number of rows of subplots get larger. Even I use TileSpacing = 'tight', there are still big vertical spaces among subplots (when I have 3 columns).

Comment: “Tight” is not supposed to have big vertical spacing. Are you combining `tiledlayout` and `subplot` maybe? Oh, maybe it’s because you’re displaying images with a fixed aspect ratio, so the tiling just doesn’t fit the figure window?

Comment: If the latter is the issue, see here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/display-multiple-images.html